# Probability of seeing an ace before seeing a two in a 52 card deck?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have a shuffled, standard 52 card deck with 4 Aces and 4 twos. I am confused about the probability of seeing an ace before seeing a two.

By symmetry, it seems obvious that the probability should be $0.5$, since the probability of seeing one before the other is equal.

But when I think of it this way: given the order of the aces in a shuffled deck, each "two" card have an equal chance of being placed in any of 5 "buckets":
[image]

So the probability of seeing an ace first is the probabiltiy that all "two"s lands in the latter 4 of the buckets. And since each one has an equal probability of landing in each other buckets, we have $P = (4/5)^4 = 0.4096$ . But that's different from the intuitive answer of $0.5$ given by symmetry! So what went wrong?

Comment: My comment clearly doesn't answer your question, but you are assuming that 5 buckets actually *exists*. Which may not be the case, if two aces in the shuffled decks are placed in a row (i.e., [whatever], A, A, [whatever]). This example illustrate why probably thinking on a "bucket" perspective" is not the proper way of handling this question

Comment: I don't understand why you'd believe selecting all 4 twos and a single ace into your 5 buckets is not a substantial probability event for which you need to apply probability rules to get the total probability.

Comment: What I think you're trying to describe is that, sampling sequentially from the deck, anything non-ace and non-two is a non-event, so you may as well have only 8 key-cards without any loss of generality, as such can we work inductively to derive the sampling distribution for 7 key-cards, 6 key-cards, and so on. This is a long winded process, but the result should be the same as your "intuition".

Comment: @user89547235 It's true that a certain "bucket" may not exist as you pointed out. However, I think one thing to consider here is that each of the 5 "bucket" have equal probability of existing or not existing. So by symmetry, any non-ace card have an equal probability of being placed in any of the buckets. But what I failed to consider, I think, is the fact that even though each of the "two"s have 1/5 probability of being in any of the bucket, the events are not independent so I cannot simply multiply them together.